# How to change font for PDF files on Edge?

Tags: pdf, fonts, microsoft-edge

Since 1 year, all PDFs without embedded fonts are rendered in a strange way on Edge (Canary):
[image: font example on Edge (Canary)]

On all other Browsers, I see it with the right font, or at least with something better:
[image: font example on Firefox]

I tried to change the font in the Edge->Settings->Font options. But it never changes. The most PDF have this font and I am not able to change it. All webpages are rendered in the right way. It is just the PDF-viewer that use this font family.

I tried to find this strange font in the system font to remove it, but I can't find it.

So, the question: is there a way to change the font used by the Edge PDF viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to search for this issue and found that probably this issue caused by the font named **Alien League** or **Alien League Tech**.

If this font is installed on your machine then you can uninstall it may help to fix this issue.

If you are not using this font then it can be possible that some other bad font has caused this issue.

Make sure that you restart the machine after removing the font.

If you want detailed information about this issue then I suggest you refer threads below.

1. [Google chrome rendering pdf fonts incorrectly](https://superuser.com/questions/1235124/google-chrome-rendering-pdf-fonts-incorrectly)
2. [Wrong, "graffiti" font in apps and Web pages after upgrade to Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/wrong-graffiti-font-in-apps-and-web-pages-after/eb9f39c0-989a-41a0-91d6-8b8ac44cc298?auth=1)

From your description, it looks like you are using the Edge Canary version. The official [Edge Chromium browser](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4501095/download-the-new-microsoft-edge-based-on-chromium) was already launched. I suggest you use it and keep up to date your Windows OS too.

Comment: Thank you! The font "Alien5" was not visible in the system fonts and wasn't set in the registry. I found it only over the powershell. The same effect was present on the Canary and the official Edge browser. But after removing the font, my PDF returned to show the PDF in the right manner. Thank you very much!